# My RESTful API with Node/Express wrong codification of caracters

Tags: java, node.js

I have an applicaction that makes a post request inserting a user like this:

```
email=Ali@gmail.com&name=Alí
```

But then hits the server with a wired caracter

```
...
body: {
   email: Ali@gmail.com,
   name: Al?
}
```

And is like this how is save in the database.

My code in the server is simple

```
router.post('user', (req, res) => {
        const newUser = new User({
            email: req.body.email,
            name: req.body.name
        });

        newUser.save().then((usr) => {
            const resp = { user: usr.fields(), code: 200 };
            return res.status(200).send(resp);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });  
});
```

The client is using HTTPConnection in Java:

```
       StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        obj = new URL(url);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(3306);

        //add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("charset",  "utf-8");

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        if (params != null) {
            wr.writeBytes(params);
        }
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: What character encoding is the client using?

Comment: I edit the question with the client information

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java, but make sure that `charset` is part of the `Content-Type` header: https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index#scripting Also, `writeBytes` needs to actually output UTF-8-encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should escape the "í" character in your url request (client side).

Something like

```
email=Ali@gmail.com&name=Al%ED%20%0A
```